# Why is R markdown not able to format my patchwork figure?

Tags: ggplot2, markdown, patchwork

I have a question regarding markdown and patchwork. Let's say I combined figures FigureLength and FigureWidth to make CombinedFigure through patchwork (two figures on top of each other):

```
library(datasets)
library(patchwork)
data(iris)

FigureLength <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()

FigureWidth <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot()

CombinedFigure <- FigureLength / FigureWidth
```

[Both figures nicely on top of each other in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E46T.png)

```
save(CombinedFigure, file = here::here ("CombinedFigure"))
```

In Markdown when I put the following only Sepal Length appears in my word document and not both figures on top of each other.

````
```{r CombinedFigure,   dpi = 300, echo = FALSE}
CombinedFigure
```
````

[What appears in markdown - only one figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YqiL.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  At the moment you are unlikely to get much help as you have not provided enough information for your issue to be reproduced.

Comment: Dear @RitchieSacramento I have tried to do this now see edits, forgive me

Comment: Thank you for adding some additional info but please also include the full (minimal and reproducible) rmarkdown code.  I get the correct result if I create it myself, so the issue is likely in your code which is why we ask for a complete **reproducible** example.

Comment: I got the expected result when running:  ---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---



```{r, include=FALSE}

library(datasets)
library(patchwork)
library(tidyverse)


data(iris)

FigureLength <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()

FigureWidth <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot()

CombinedFigure <- FigureLength / FigureWidth
```


```{r CombinedFigure,   dpi = 300, echo = FALSE}
CombinedFigure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the following code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "4/4/2022"
output: word_document
---

```{r}
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
data(iris)

FigureLength <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()

FigureWidth <- iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot()

CombinedFigure <- FigureLength / FigureWidth
```

```{r CombinedFigure,   dpi = 300, echo = FALSE}
CombinedFigure
```
````

I to get both figures nicely on top of each other in WORD like this:

[image]